# Java - Date decreased by one day randomly serializing and deserializing that date

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I have a strange problem in production: a Java.util.Date field is decreased by **one day** totaly randomly.
It **rarely** happens but sometime something goes wrong and the date is decreased in production.

Trying to create custom serializer and deserializer didn't help.

Here is the code:

```
// UserData class

package mypackage;

import myotherpackage.DataDefaultPatternDeserializer;
import myotherpackage.DataDefaultPatternSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import lombok.Data;
import java.util.Date;

@Data
public class UserData {
    //Random problems in production - date decreased by one day
    @JsonSerialize(using = DataDefaultPatternSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = DataDefaultPatternDeserializer.class)
    private Date dateOfBirth;
}


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// DataDefaultPatternSerializer class

package myotherpackage;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class DataDefaultPatternSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> {
    public DataDefaultPatternSerializer() {
    }

    public void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd").withLocale(Locale.ITALY);
        jsonGenerator.writeString(formatter.print(new DateTime(date)));
    }
}


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// DataDefaultPatternDeserializer class

package myotherpackage;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class DataDefaultPatternDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date> {
    public DataDefaultPatternDeserializer() {
    }

    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd").withLocale(Locale.ITALY);
        String dateString = jsonParser.getText();
        return formatter.parseDateTime(dateString).toDate();
    }
}
```

Any solution?

Comment: It'll be timezones, and it won't be random. Remember that the same moment in time can be on different calendar days in different timezones.

Comment: Thank you @T.J.Crowder, is there any solution to have the correct DoB in our timezone?

Comment: DOB is tricky, I usually use a character column for it but have always felt like there was a better answer. The important thing is that typically "date of birth" is the date in the timezone where the birth occurred. For instance, if my DOB is `YYYY-MM-14`, it's `YYYY-MM-14` even if you're in a location where, at the moment I was born on that day, it was the 13th or 15th rather than the 14th. :-)

Comment: @Ex. how exactly did you caught the error? Was an inbound, outbound request or just database data that is stored incorrectly?

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos data came from a REST request, server and client were in the same timezone

Comment: @Ex. ok, so a request came inside your application. Where was the error identified? In the stored element in database or when your application sent another request outside?

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos my application called another external service, a SOAP service, and in that request the date was decriesed by one day

Answer (score 0):

## Wrong type

Never use either `Date` class. These terrible classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Also, `java.util.Date` represents a moment, a date with time-of-day as seen in UTC, with an offset of zero hits-minutes-seconds. You were trying to fit a date-only value (date of birth) into a date-with-time-in-UTC type.

## Time zones

The reason for the date and time appearing to change on your `java.util.Date` is that the class has among its many design flaws a `toString` method that dynamically applies the JVM’s current default time zone while generating the text. When adjusting a moment into another time zone, the time-of-day and even the date may "change". Right now at this moment as I write this it is "tomorrow" [in Tokyo Japan](https://time.is/Tokyo) while simultaneously "yesterday" [in Toledo Ohio US](https://Time%20in%20Tokyo,%20Japan%20now05:53:08am).

> Tokyo, Japan now 05:53:08 AM on 2022-03-19 Saturday
>
> Toledo, Ohio, US now 04:53:08 PM on 2022-03-18 Friday

The best solution for this issue is to (a) not use the legacy `java.util.Date` class, and (b) not use a date-with-time-in-UTC type to represent a date-only value.

## `java.time.LocalDate`

For a date of birth, use a date-only type, `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "1969-01-23" ) ;
```

To generate text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, call `toString`.

```
String outputISO8601 = ld.toString() ;
```

## Serializing

When serializing date-time values to text, use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats.

Jackson supports the *java.time* types.

## Database

To write to a database in a column of a type akin to the SQL-standard type `DATE`:

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ld ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```